# overwrite the existing data when there is a new one using pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have two tables:

```
1,'hello'
2,'world'
4,'this'
```

and

```
1,'john'
3,'king'
```

and I want to produce a table

```
1,'john'
2,'world',
3,'king'
4,'this'
```

I need the code columns to combine, how can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Get records that are only in A and then UNION it with B.

```
A = LOAD 'test1.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (aid:int,aname:chararray);
B = LOAD 'test2.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (bid:int,bname:chararray);
C = JOIN A BY aid LEFT OUTER,B BY bid;
D = FILTER C BY bid is null;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE A::aid,A::aname;
F = UNION E,B;
DUMP F;
```

Note:If you want it in order then sort the final relation F.

```
G = ORDER F BY F.$0;
DUMP G;
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: simple and smart, i love it !